# Meaning of 言いだしっぺとして

Tags: meaning, expressions

I stumbled upon the following sentence:

> 言いだしっぺとして、10人がんばります！

Context: a person is told to invite 10 persons, and seems to answer "言いだしっぺとして, I will try my best to get 10 persons!"

What does the 言いだしっぺとして part mean?
What nuance does it bring to the sentence, compared to a simple "10人がんばります！"?

Comment: Is anyone able to comment on the etymology of this term? where does the っぺ come from and is it used in other words?

Comment: @無色受想行識 It's [言い出しっ屁](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/9497/m0u/言出しっぺ/).  大辞泉 says 《最初に臭いと言い出した者が、おならをした当人だという意から》

Comment: @snailboat そのリンク開くと「指定されたドキュメントは存在しません。」って出てきますね。辞書自体がなくなったのでしょうか。

Comment: I changed it to link to goo! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`言い出しっぺ` is a single word and if you check a dictionary you get: 'the one who brought it up'.
Since he is the one who originally proposed the idea of getting 10 people, it is his responsibility to carry out his proposal, is what he is saying.