# っぺがやる following 連用形

Tags: grammar

Spoken in a dialogue:

> こういうのは言いだしっぺがやるもんだろ

As far as I can tell from context, it's "As if it were me who brought that up!" (it wasn't me, it was you!). However, I can't find any explanation on the web as to what っぺがやる (or is it っぺ ＋ bound particle ＋ やる? or case particle?) following RY form of a verb actually means. I'd be grateful if someone could please explain this structure.

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13089/meaning-of-%E8%A8%80%E3%81%84%E3%81%A0%E3%81%97%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BA%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the article referred to by Choko?

If not, the following might be of help:

```
こういうのは言いだしっぺがやるもんだろ
```

which is decomposed to

```
こういうの + は + [言いだしっぺ + が + やる + もん] + だろ
```

- こういうの <- こういうもの This (kind of things, items etc.)
- は indicates that こういうの is the subject for this entire sentence.
- 言いだしっぺ one who (have) brought up
- が indicates (with stress) that 言いだしっぺ is the subject for the verb やる.
- やる, to do, to carry out.
- もん <- もの thing, item...
- だろ <- だろう　is(n't it?)

Together they mean

```
This is what should be carried out by the one who brought it up, right?
```